# How to access a value in a list when for + for_each in a dynamic resource wrapped by for_each - Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-template-file

In the following code (not the cleanest ) I need to access each value on the init-script list and pass it to the dynamic "init-scripts" block.
when I try to use each.value, terraform returns the var.cluster attributes but not the values of the list. How do I access the value of the list. Appreciate your help with this.

```
variable "clusters" {
  type = map(object({
    cluster-name            = string
    init-scripts            = list(string)

  }))

}

resource "databricks_cluster" "cluster" {
  for_each = var.clusters

  cluster_name = each.key

dynamic "init_scripts" {
    for_each = { for script in var.clusters[each.key].init-scripts : script => script if var.clusters[each.key].init-scripts != null }
    content {
      file {
        destination = each.value #returns the value of var.clusters
        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a simple fix. Iterator seem to solve the issue.

```
  dynamic "init_scripts" {
    for_each = { for script in var.clusters[each.key].init-scripts : script => script if var.clusters[each.key].init-scripts != null }
    iterator = script
    content {
      file {
        destination = script.value
      }
    }
  }
```